# ColdFusion/Java Class not found Exception

Tags: java, coldfusion, classnotfoundexception, opencsv

I am trying to parse a CSV File with Coldfusion and a JavaLibrary. I found some examples but it seems that ColdFusion cannot find the Jar-File.

This is my Code:

```
<cfset t01= getTickCount()>
    <cfscript>
        fileReader = createobject("java","java.io.FileReader");
        fileReader.init("C:\Dev\files.csv");
        csvReader = createObject("java","au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader");
        csvReader.init(fileReader, ",");
    </cfscript>

<cfset t02= getTickCount()>
<cfset ArrayData = csvReader.readAll()>
<cfset t03= getTickCount()>

<cfoutput>
    Process Data: #t02 - t01# ms
    Display Dump: #t03 - t02# ms
    <cfdump var="ArrayData"><cfabort />
</cfoutput>
```

and this is the ErrorMessage:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapClassLoader.loadClass(BootstrapClassLoader.java:235)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248).....more Stack blabla......
```

I am using the [opencsv Library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).
The Jar File is in the following folder:

> wwwroot/WEB-INF/lib

I also restarted the Server multiple times.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the opencsv jar file and it looks like you might be referencing it incorrectly.

Instead of this:

```
csvReader = createObject("java","au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader");
```

Try this:

```
csvReader = createObject("java","com.opencsv.CSVReader");
```

*I was looking at the latest version, 3.3, but I assume that hasn't changed.*

**From the comments (my assumption was incorrect)**

As Leigh pointed out in the comments, older versions of the opencsv library used a different package name than the latest version does.  Old versions used `au.com.bytecode.opencsv` but the new versions use `com.opencsv`.

Comment: @noah - I suspect Miguel-F hit the nail on the head. Looking at the source, older versions (2.2 for example) used a different package name ie `au.com.bytecode.opencsv`. In [newer versions](http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/release-3.2/tree/examples/AddressExample.java#l1) the package name was switched to `com.opencsv`. You are probably using one of the newer jars, but with the old package name. Hence why it is not found. The above should solve the problem.

Comment: How to run same snippet in "ram:///"? I was stuck with it. Seems fileReader can not process in-memory path.